# Is it possible to define your own evaluation function in Keras?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

According to this thread: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/49109/loss-val-loss-are-decreasing-but-accuracies-are-the-same-in-lstm when we use `metrics='accuracy'` during training of neural network in `Keras`, what happens under the hood is:

```
if metric in ('accuracy', 'acc'):
    metric_fn = metrics_module.binary_accuracy
```

where

```
def binary_accuracy(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.mean(K.equal(y_true, K.round(y_pred)), axis=-1)
```

In my model I am dealing with continuous data, for which using different evaluation function would be more applicable. Is it possible, to change this predefined metric to something custom made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found an answer. We can define our metric as follows:

```
def my_metric(y_true, y_pred):
    ...
```

and then just use it in the following way:

```
model.compile(optimizer='...', loss='...', metrics=[my_metric])
```